# Accidentally calling an ovverriden method from base class's __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program seems to do everything by the book, yet this issue cropped up: while a base class was being init'ed a member method was called that is overriden in the derived class and assumes that the derived class has been constructed.

Is there some best practice to protect against this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ax = 1
        print(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} ax: {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.ax)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bx = 10

    def __repr__(self):
        return super().__repr__() + " bx: {}".format(self.bx)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    B()
```

And here's the error:

```
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'bx'
```

Comment: Put `bx = 10` before the `super()` call?

Comment: You are missing self.bx

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "protect against it". Protect against what exactly?

Comment: sorry, i fixed the self.bx typo and error message, does not change the essence of the question

Comment: @glibdud when calling methods from __init__, you are not protected from your the class being overriden in the future and those methods being called from the derived class, which is not constructed yet.

Comment: Sure, in that case it's the subclass's responsibility to not cause these situations. Evert gave an example of how that can be done here.

Comment: Step 1 is to consider whether subclassing should even be a supported way of using class A. People tend to just assume that any class should be a usable superclass, but designing an API for subclass-superclass interaction and implementing it properly actually takes a lot of conscious effort. You run into problems with initialization order, and with overridden methods being used internally in ways that assume the overridden behavior, and unexpected circular dependencies. For example, your `A` assumes that after `A.__init__`, the object is completely initialized...

Comment: or at least, initialized enough to call `__repr__`. That conflicts with subclassing, and while you can sort of work around the problem by rearranging your `__init__` calls, trying to solve things that way leads to a mess where different classes need to be very careful about calling superclass `__init__` methods at the start, the end, or even somewhere in the middle of their `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, unless you really know what you are doing, you want to call the superclass initialization after everything your class needs to do is done. Same with this example, **repr** is trying to print self.bx before you initialize it. If you do

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bx = 10
        super().__init__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return super().__repr__() + " bx: {}".format(self.bx)
```

it works as expected

Comment: I'm not sure this is a widely applicable fix (it seems as likely that calling the base class initializer first is important to not break methods called in the derived class's `__init__`), but it's clearly the right answer in this specific case.

Comment: General principles of OO programming say that you should not worry about derived classes. Your concern should be that your class works. Any problems derived classes might have should be solved in the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Instead of doing computation on `__init__`, one idea may be to do that in a factory function/classmethod.

Example instead of doing:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        # do some things
```

Do:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def from_a_b(cls, a, b):
        instance = cls(a, b)
        instance.initialize()
        return instance
```

Comment: Did you try running it? It still produces the error.

Comment: Oh that's true. `print` calls `__repr__` that doesn't have `self.bx` yet.

Comment: that was a typo in my message, fixed it already. That was not the issue